# GROUPING BY DATETIME IN SAS DATA STEP

Tags: datastep

My data is in below form

```
account_no  transaction_start_dt_tm       RECTYPE   
34842765    23APR2017:14:34:00.000000        ICU      
34842765    25APR2017:17:26:00.000000        ICU      
34842765    28APR2017:14:18:00.000000        LLOC
```

I want to enumerate rectype within the group that includes both account_no AND transaction_start_dt_tm. Account_no is constant, but transaction_start_dt_tm never repeats and Rectype has values of (ICU, LLOC). I want my output to be as shown below.

```
account_no  transaction_start_dt_tm       RECTYPE   RECNO_1 CNT
34842765    23APR2017:14:34:00.000000        ICU       1    1
34842765    25APR2017:17:26:00.000000        ICU       2    2
34842765    28APR2017:14:18:00.000000        LLOC      3    1
```

Comment: can you show us by sample data you starting point from where you want the output

Comment: account_no transaction_start_dt_tm           RECTYPE     CNT
34842765 23APR2017:14:34:00.000000  ICU              1
34842765 25APR2017:17:26:00.000000  ICU              2
34842765 28APR2017:14:18:00.000000         LLOC      1

Comment: so you want only RECNO_1 column, i mean that us tge new column, so do you have already cnt column

Comment: For each account_no, everytime there is a change in RECTYPE I want it to enumerate. BUT it has to stay in transaction_start_dt_tm order

Comment: I resolved my problem by including the NOTSORTED in my BY statement in my datastep and only include ACCOUNT_NO AND RECTYPE

Comment: you can write your solution as answer